# Which Framework is required for developing android application ? MVC/MVP/MVVM

Tags: android, frameworks, puremvc

As I am going to start developing an android application. So just wanted to discuss which framework should I follow ? MVC / PureMVC / MVP / MVVM ? if yes, then why ?

I have researched alot but didn't get any idea on this..

Also I wanted to know Is it required to use these frameworks in developing android application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantages of using MVC pattern is already there in current android framework, you have your views seprately, Your activity class file is called first and you assign the view to it. you can have models which can be use for populating your views through controller.

Other than above, I dont really feel any advantage of using any pattern in android application. No Doubt you can design your application to follow any one of pattern but you will just add more files/complexity to your project and that will also take more time.

Comment: The assumption that Android apps implement MVC by design is wrong. Contrary to iOS, Android app architecture does not promote separation of concerns. If you want MVC on Android (or any variant such as MVP) you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it required to use these frameworks in developing android application ?

None of those architectural patterns are required. Android was not designed to follow any of those patterns specifically.

Comment: But why ? These frameworks seprates the model, view , controller ?

Answer (score 0):

To get started with Android, you will need to download the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and choose a suitable editor or Integrated Development Environment (IDE). Whilst it is technically possible to create an android app utilising a standard text editor and command line tools, I would wholly recommend going the IDE route, particularly for a beginner.

There are three main IDE's I would consider, in the order of my personal preference:

- Eclipse IDE
- IntelliJ IDEA
- Android Studio (Unstable)

(unfortunately due to my reputation I cannot post links to the above).

The "frameworks" you mentioned aren't really frameworks, they are software architecture patterns, however many of the methodologies that these patterns promote are present in the Android SDK, particularly the separation of data, presentation and business logic.

I would highly recommend reading through the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) that Google provides, particularly the **API guides** and **Training** sections.